# Python Array is read-only, can't append values

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to Python.  The following code is causing an error when it attempts to append values to an array.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import re
from array import array

freq_pattern = re.compile("Frequency of Incident[\(\)A-Za-z\s]*\.*\s*([\.0-9]*)")
col_pattern = re.compile("([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)")
e_rcs = array('f')

f = open('example.4.out', 'r')

for line in f:
    print line,

    result = freq_pattern.search(line)
    if result:
        freq = float(result.group(1))

    cols = col_pattern.search(line)
    if cols:
        e_rcs.append = float(cols.group(2))

f.close()
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\workspace\CATS
>   Parser\cats-post.py", line 31, in
>   
>       e_rcs.append = float(cols.group(2)) AttributeError:
>   'list' object attribute 'append' is
>   read-only attributes (assign to .append)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning to the append() function, you want instead to call .append(float(cols.group(2))).

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to append to the array?

```
e_rcs.append( float(cols.group(2)) )
```

Doing this: `e_rcs.append = float(cols.group(2))` replaces the `append` method of the array `e-rcs` with a floating-point value.  Rarely something you want to do.

Comment: He's not calling a list an array.  He's using an array, from the array module that is part of Python's standard library.

Comment: I have n floats to store. Traditionally I would use arrays in other languages. That is what I am trying to use in Python with little success. What data type should I be using in Python?

Comment: @Jared Brown: numpy arrays are fine.  Some people say "array" when they're using the built-in "list" type.  I failed to read the numpy array part at the beginning.

Comment: You probably want a plain ol' list. It is similar to vanilla arrays in other languages.

Comment: @Nick What is the advantage to using a List in this case over an array('f')?

Comment: @S.Lott So is numpy part of Python?  Is using array('f') using numpy?

Comment: @Jared Brown.  `numpy` is an add-on library.  It's similar to `array` in that it's external.  Both are optimized for storage of large, large numbers of similar values.  A `list` is built-in, does not require an `import` and is a more general (but slower) structure.

Comment: in the scientific community, i've never seen anyone use the `array` library.  *everyone* uses numpy.  just an FYI if anyone was curious.

Comment: @Autoplectic: I read "numpy" even though the code actually says "array".  I'm so used to `numpy` that I assumed it without benefit of evidence.  :-(

Answer (score 3):

append is a method.  You're trying to overwrite it instead of calling it.

```
e_rcs.append(float(cols.group(2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import re

freq_pattern = re.compile("Frequency of Incident[\(\)A-Za-z\s]*\.*\s*([\.0-9]*)")
col_pattern = re.compile("([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)\s+([-\.0-9]+)")
e_rcs = [] # make an empty list

f = open('example.4.out', 'r')

for line in f:
    print line,

    result = freq_pattern.search(line)
    if result:
        freq = float(result.group(1))

    cols = col_pattern.search(line)
    if cols:
        e_rcs.append( float(cols.group(2)) ) # add another float to the list

f.close()
```

In Python you would only use array.array when you need to control the binary layout of your storage, i.e. a plain array of bytes in RAM.

If you are going to be doing a lot of scientific data analysis, then you should have a look at the [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) module which supports n-dimensional arrays. Think of NumPy as a replacement for FORTRAN in doing mathematics and data analysis.