# Python equivalent to assigning to an array (inside for loop) in Matlab

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, append

This is a pretty simple question, I've written a lot in case people find this that were a few hours behind me on the 'WHY WON'T THIS WORK?' train, to help them out

---

In Matlab, the following code would create a dynamically increasing-in-size array:

```
for i = 1:5
    array(i) = i*2;
end
```

but I am having some problems with the complexities in Python. The following does work but isn't exactly what I want:

```
i = []
array = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    array.append(i*2)
```

This works however you can only append to the end. You can also allocate values to a range of cells that already exist - beyond simply 'stick them on the end' (i.e. the below code which could replace cells 14-36 in a 100 cell long list)

```
i = []
array = list(xrange(1,100)) #creates list from 1 to 99
for i in range(14, 36):
    array[i] = i*2 #assign and overwrite previous cell values
```

Is there some catch-all coding method here that combines the two? A solution to the following code:

```
i = []
array = list(xrange(1,50)) #creates list from 1 to 49
for i in range(34, 66):
    array[i] = i*2
```

Error message:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

**General differences I've seen so far:**

- Python starts at cell number [0] not [1]
- You can't dynamically update list sizes and so you need to use the append function
- (Possibly?) need to preallocate the lists before using them

**
**Note for others struggling:**

One error that consistently came up was:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
```

This was due to trying to assign a value like this:

```
array.append[i-1] = i*2
```

See higher up for the correct method.

**Misc.**

Thanks for any help! I'm sure this is really simple but I have run out of ideas and can't find a solution in previous questions!

Other similar questions that either didn't solve it or I didn't understand:

- ["TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232313/typeerror-function-object-does-not-support-item-assignment)
- [Python Array is read-only, can't append values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651430/python-array-is-read-only-cant-append-values)
- http://www.pythonbackend.com/topic/1329787069?reply=3

Comment: In your section where you say "A solution to the following code", you make a list from 1 to 49 but claim it goes to 99. That would explain why going to 66 is out of range.

Comment: Also, `list(xrange(1, 50))` is an inefficient way to write `range(1, 50)`.

Comment: May I ask why you would want such a behaviour? If you pre-allocate your list, I would expect you wouldn't want to assign values to elements outside the allocated range.

Comment: @dpwilson sorry it was supposed to go out of range, I was showing the issue I was trying to solve. I've updated the comment. And thanks for the other code shortening, I'm still learning and so most of this is copypasta and editing from different places. I've made a note of the quicker way, thanks!

Comment: @Lisa I'm hoping the end result to be auto-processing of datasets that update in real-time on the server. I was hoping that if I could extend lists beyond the previous range that it would save me from needing to reimport all the data each time - I could instead just import the new data and append it to the end. And considering it's got a 100Hz sampling rate, there would always be some variation in the input data's list lengths

Comment: @Lisa I forgot to say: recent data on the server can change due to other auto-processing scripts that run and so I would want to import and replace the last x-mins of data, not just append new stuff to the end.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to familiarize yourself with numpy as a minimum if you're going to get close to Matlab-like functionality in python. The following is a useful reference:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try to avoid dynamically increasing the size of your list altogether (in MATLAB as well as python) unless you have a good reason to do so. Maybe you could check the desired (final) size of your list elsewhere in the code, before allocation.

So I would go along the same lines as one of your suggestions, with the difference that you can allocate an empty list like so:

```
arr = [None] * 100

for i in range(100):
    arr[i] = i*2
```

Or, as John Greenall suggested, use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty(100)

for i in range(100):
    arr[i] = i*2
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm hoping to create a script that auto-processes data and so I'll be importing new data (where last few files of old data may have changed) to process with previous data.
Without dynamically increasing the size or appending, my guess is:
# cut the new import in half
# overwrite old data with corrected data
# preallocate length of a new list
# then populate it with the two separate lists (the old+corrected data and the new data) / Dynamically updating the list would allow me to just go from the first new file and overwrite/append all future data in one for loop. Is there a simpler way?